# MS Access VBA SQL query using multiple AND operators fails?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table (tbl_Avail) that shows availability for different people on certain dates and on certain parts of the particular day. I am trying to make a query that counts the number of people available on multiple dates AND on certain times on those days.

tbl_Avail:  (Pas1 & Pas2 (Boolean) indicates the 2 periods of the day that I am searching for availability for. True indicates available - false, not available)

```
ID   Student   Date_Avail    Pas1    Pas2
1    Joe       2020/08/09    x
2    Bob       2020/08/09            x
3    Pete      2020/08/09    x
4    Joe       2020/08/08    x       x
5    Bob       2020/08/08    x
6    Pete      2020/08/08    x       x
```

In this example I am searching for the number of people available (true) on date 2020/08/08 Pas2 AND on 2020/08/09 Pas1, but when I run the query it returns 0 - my expected result would be 2, as both Joe and Pete are available in Pas2 on the 8th and in Pas1 on the 9th.

My query:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim StudentsAvail As Long

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Count(*) AS StudentsTotal FROM tbl_Avail WHERE ((Pas1=true AND Date_Avail= #2020/08/09#) and (Date_Avail=#2020/08/08# AND Pas2=true))")
StudentsAvail = rs!StudentsTotal
```

If I change the query to only use …. WHERE Pas1=true and Date_Avail= #2020/08/09# for example, it works correctly. There are no error codes - it just counts 0.

I you have any idea as to what I am doing wrong, or have a better solution please let me know:-)
Thank you.
Peter

Comment: Your query criteria will never be meet, as there no Date_Avail can be `#2020/08/08#` **AND** `#2020/08/09#`. You want to connect both conditions "(Pas1=true AND Date_Avail= #2020/08/09#" , "Date_Avail=#2020/08/08# AND Pas2=true)" with **OR** operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS StudentsTotal
FROM (SELECT Student
      FROM tbl_Avail
      GROUP BY Student
      HAVING SUM(IIF(Pas1 = true AND Date_Avail = #2020/08/09#, 1, 0)) > 0 AND
             SUM(IIF(Pas2 = true AND Date_Avail = #2020/08/08#, 1, 0)) > 0
     ) as s;
```

The subquery returns the students with both conditions true.  If uses a `HAVING` clause because the conditions are true on different rows.

The outer query counts the students.

Comment: That worked perfectly:-) What does the "1, 0" do after the dates?

Comment: @Sapster77 . . . Those are arguments to `IIF()` -- when the condition is true and when not true.

Comment: @Sapster77, they are the results of the IIF expression. When criteria is true, it returns 1 (representing true) or 0(false), when criteria is false. All results are added then (`SUM`)  and compared if greater zero. That results (True or False) are conjuncted by AND Operator  (only true if both true).. Now you can use that as criteria on a sub-query, that only returns  rows matching that criteria and you can aggregate (Count) on that result.

Comment: Would it be possible to update a boolean column, "Ready", to true in a separate table, "tbl_ready", with the result from the subquery (the column "Student" is present in both tables)? E.g. the student names that are returned from the subquery should be set to true in column "Ready" in "tbl_ready". I tried an UPDATE tbl_ready SET Student = true WHERE Student = (SELECT Student FROM tbl_Avail...etc. ), but get a runtime 3354 "At most 1 record can be returned by this subquery".

Comment: @Sapster77 . . . That sounds possible -- although a bit complicated and outside the scope of this question.